# How to enable click preview in jetpack compose preview function in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I have this composable function:

```
@Composable
fun GreetingText(name: String) {
    Text(text = "Hello $name!", modifier = Modifier
        .padding(24.dp)
        .clickable { }
    )
}
```

And this preview function:

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    SampleTextTheme {
        GreetingText("world")
    }
}
```

This is my **version of android studio**: *Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2*

This is the preview design that android studio gives me:

[image: Hello world android studio preview]

I believe that by inserting the `ciclckable {}` function into my `Modifier` android studio should provide me with a tool in the preview design that would make it easier to see what would happen visually when I click on the element.

Comment: Hey, what tool are u expecting? because you have no code written inside the clickable function.

Comment: I was hoping that android studio would provide me with some visual click feedback tool in the composable preview function, I believe this is independent of the function having a code inside `.clickable { }` since it is a matherial component.

Comment: have you added `ui-tooling` dependency in your application `build.gradle` file?`debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"`

Comment: Yes. That's not the problem. I just marked the right answer. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in [Interactive mode](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling#preview-interactive).

Right now this feature is experimental, so you should [enable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling#enable-experimental-features) it within Android Studio preferences.

[image]